# Elasticsearch bulk update followed by search

Tags: asynchronous, elasticsearch, bulk

In my server I update some documents using bulk API:

```
{"update":{"_type":"post","_retry_on_conflict":"3","_index":"xxxx","_id":"yyyy"}}
{"doc":{"sentiment":"positive","mood":1,"upgrade":true}}
```

After I get the response I make a new request for the same document using search:

```
{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"ids":{"values":["yyyy"]}}}}}
```

But the returned document has no updated value( Still has the old value ). If I wait for some time the updated value appears. I Think that occurs because bulk is async? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) api to force index update, or even add `?refresh=true` at the end of bulk command. But normally not recommended. Also, If there are more than one Node, you may need to use [synced flush](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush.html).

Comment: The `refresh=true` parameter can also be added to the bulk request URL itself, i.e. no need to make a second call just for that.

Comment: @jirico I think so, I can't find any other reason.